# Mocking Ajax.IsRequest to return False

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am trying to mock the Ajax.IsRequest() method of ASP.Net MVC. I found out how to do it in order for it to return true:

```
Expect.Call(_myController.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]).Return("XMLHttpRequest").Repeat.Any();
```

This works and returns true. Now I need to test the other branch of the code. How can I mock it to return false? I have tried removing the mock altogether, It fails with:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]

If I do:

```
Expect.Call(_templateReportController.Request["X-Requested-With"]).Return(null).Repeat.Any();
```

It fails with the same error.

Entire Test:

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Tests the Edit Action when calling via Ajax
    /// </summary>
    [Test]
    public void Test_Edit_AjaxRequest()
    {
        Group group = new Group();
        group.ID = 1;
        group.Name = "Admin";
        IList<Group> groupList = new List<Group>() { group };

        Definition def  = new Definition();
        def.ID = 1;
        def.Name = "Report";
        def.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
        def.Groups.Add(group);


        using (_mocks.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(_myController.Request["X-Requested-With"]).Return("XMLHttpRequest").Repeat.Any();
            Expect.Call(_DefBiz.GetAll<Group>()).Return(groupList);
            Expect.Call(_DefBiz.Get<Definition>(1)).Return(def);
        }

        myController.DefAccess = _DefBiz;
        PartialViewResult actual;

        using (_mocks.Playback())
        {
            actual = (PartialViewResult)myController.Edit(1);
        }


    }
```

Any advices?
Cheers

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929058/newbie-question-on-mvccontrib-testhelpers

Comment: As I mentioned I can get it to mock it to return true, which the code samples in that question does, but I can't seem to get it to return false.

Comment: Could you paste the whole test that works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your are getting `NullReferenceException` is because you never stubbed the `controller.Request` object in your unit test and when you invoke the controller action which uses `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` it throws.

Here's how you could mock the context using `Rhino.Mocks`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Ajax()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new HomeController();
    var context = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>();
    context.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(request);
    // indicate AJAX request
    request.Stub(x => x["X-Requested-With"]).Return("XMLHttpRequest");
    sut.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context, new RouteData(), sut);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Index();

    // assert
    // TODO: ...
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test_Non_Ajax()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new HomeController();
    var context = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>();
    context.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(request);
    sut.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context, new RouteData(), sut);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Index();

    // assert
    // TODO: ...
}
```

---

And here's a better alternative (which I would personally recommend you) in order to avoid all the plumbing code. Using  [MVCContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) (which is based on `Rhino.Mocks`) your unit test might be simplified to this:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTests : TestControllerBuilder
{
    private HomeController _sut;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize() 
    {
        _sut = new HomeController();
        this.InitializeController(_sut);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void HomeController_Index_Ajax()
    {
        // arrange
        _sut.Request.Stub(x => x["X-Requested-With"]).Return("XMLHttpRequest");

        // act
        var actual = _sut.Index();

        // assert
        // TODO: ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void HomeController_Index_Non_Ajax()
    {
        // act
        var actual = _sut.Index();

        // assert
        // TODO: ...
    }
}
```

Much prettier. It also allows you to write much more expressive asserts on the action results. Checkout the doc or ask if for more info is needed.

Comment: Cheers. Gonna try this (and that framework, seems like it will make my life easier. Will comment soon. Till then thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
Expect.Call(_myController.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]).Return("SpitAndDuctTape").Repeat.Any();
```

...should do the job.

Comment: Fails as Request.Headers is null. Might need to mock that as well.

Comment: You do it *exactly* as you do it for the `true` case, but change just this one line. Actually, just this one string. If the code you give works for `true`, as you claim, then there must be additional code you're not showing. Use that same code for this case.